# How can I tie a pattern to specific items in a data structure?

Tags: haskell

Consider the simple data structure below (I'm learning how to use attoparsec). Rather than just deriving show automatically, I've created an instance for it. However, that instance will immediately break (return wrong answer) if the order of the items in the DateDefinition is changed (e.g, I put dayOfMonth before monthOfYear).
There must be a way to associate each entry in the pattern with each entry in the data structure so that it's immune to changes in the order of the items. But how? I tried using the actual names but unsurprisingly that didn't work and just resulted in a warning about shadowing the existing binding.

```
data DateDefinition = DateDefinition
            {
                 monthOfYear :: Months,
                 dayOfMonth :: Int,
                 hourOfDay :: Int,
                 minuteOfHour :: Int,
                 secondOfMinute :: Int
            }

instance Show DateDefinition where
   show (DateDefinition m d _ _ _) = show m  ++  " " ++ show d
```

Comment: All of these answers are great and helpful --- I don't really know how to choose one over the others as "THE" answer. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use 'Record puns' for terse record matching with the [`NamedFieldPuns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-puns) extension:

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
    show (DateDefinition {monthOfYear, dayOfMonth}) =
        show monthOfYear ++ " " ++ show dayOfMonth
```

You can also pattern-match in a similar way without an extension:

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
    show (DateDefinition {monthOfYear = month, dayOfMonth = day}) =
        show month ++ " " ++ show day
```

If you really don't want to pattern-match, you could do it the dirtier way by using the functions that extract values:

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
    show date =
        show (monthOfYear date) ++ " " ++ show (dayOfMonth date)
```

Which is certainly terser than the others.

---

It may also be worth renaming your datatype to `Date`, and changing the functions to keep your code terse, because the names you're currently using aren't so great:

```
data Date = Date 
           { month     :: Months
           , day       :: Int
           , hour      :: Int
           , minute    :: Int
           , second    :: Int
           }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, much appreciated. I am however explicitly opposed to this notion that terseness is a good thing. My experience is that the desire to be terse is the biggest inhibitor to learning and understanding Haskell.

Comment: By the way, other than your suggestion to change the name of my structure, I don't find your function extraction suggestion to be terse, and indeed it seems to be quite readable. I'm wondering why non-pattern matching is considered "dirtier"

Comment: @David I find it 'dirtier' because it's inherently unsafe; it feels like using `head` on a list, which could easily fail, instead of pattern-matching a list.

Comment: Ah --- thank you --- that's a trade-off worth considering. Again, I appreciate your taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the field accessors directly; this is the simplest way:

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
    show dd = show (monthOfYear dd) ++ " " ++ show (dayOfMonth dd)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `RecordWildCards` extension:

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
    show DateDefinition{..} = show monthOfYear ++ " " ++ show dayOfMonth
```

Which is nice if you never plan on getting rid of those fields.  If you want to change the internal structure without breaking anything then the first implementation ([as pointed out by rampion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753482)) is probably the safest.  You can always make those fields into normal functions without anyone ever knowing, so long as you don't export the constructor.

Comment: this does future-proof against completely changing the implementation of `DateDefinition` (to something like `data DateDefinition = DateDefinition { secondsSinceEpoch :: Integer }`), since your fields can always be ported to normal functions.

Comment: I"m not sure what to make of these alternatives  (RecordWildCard vs NamedFieldPuns). Surely they would both break if I got rid of a field (and indeed that's exactly what I'm trying to detect at compile time.

Comment: If you're trying to future-proof against fields that might disappear, it would be best to use the first alternative.  It's Haskell98, easy to understand, but a bit more verbose.  If you were to change the internal representation of `DateDefinition` then you could just simply define these accessors as normal functions, and as long as you aren't using those fields to set values on the type it shouldn't break anything.  If you want a more robust system than that I would recommend looking at the lens library.

Comment: I haven't gotten to lens yet --- it's on my list but I'm still just revisiting everything to get up to speed.

Comment: @David If you haven't gotten there yet then don't worry about it.  For something as simple as this you probably don't need them anyway.  Just stick with plain old field accessors, write separate functions to set different values as you need them, and don't pattern match on the constructor.  You might not end up writing the shortest code, but you can be guaranteed that it'll be readable and more future proof than the other solutions suggested here.

Answer (score 3):

You can pattern match using the field names:

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
   show (DateDefinition { monthOfYear = m, dayOfMonth = d }) 
     = show m ++  " " ++ show d
```

<s>Alternately, if you're worried about future proofing against getting rid of those fields completely, you could use [`ViewPatterns`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns):</s>

```
instance Show DateDefinition where
   show (monthOfYear -> m)@(dayOfMonth -> d) = show m ++  " " ++ show d
```

(nope, can't do that with `@`).

Comment: One can use `show (monthOfYear &&& dayOfMonth -> (m,d)) = ...`. I'd still prefer the first alternative, though.